# Как можно реализовать данную функцию?

Tags: php

Сделать возможность добавления сообщений в базу без перезагрузки
страниц, то есть аяксом (ajax). 
Как можно реализовать?

Comment: Аяксом и реализовать. Документации про ajax и про php везде навалом, какие проблемы возникли?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в секцию `head` подключаешь библиотеку jQuery и создаем файл `ajax.js`

```
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="ajax.js"></script>
</head>
```

`html` форма

```
<form action="post.php">
 <input name="post" />
 <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

ajax.js

```
$(document).ready(function($){ // Ждем готовности страницы
 $('form').on('submit', function(e){ // после отправки формы
  var form = $(this);
  var url = form.attr('action'); // получаем URl куда будем отправлять запрос

  $.ajax({
   method: "POST",
   url: url,
   data: form.serialize(), // получаем все значения формы
  }).done(function(response){
    // Выводим результат запроса
    alert(response);
  });

  // Ставим свои умолчания на форму, что бы страница не перегружалась после отправки 
  e.preventDefault();
 });
});
```

post.php

```
$post = isset($_POST['post']) ? isset($_POST['post']) : false;
if($post)
{
 // Тут все возможные проверки на входящие данные 
 // И добавляем в базу
 exit('Добавлено!');
}else{
exit('Поле POST обязательно к заполнению');
}
```